# Making code thread safe without using the lock statement

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, locking

I want to call the following code from several threads.

```
// x is a global/member and initialized to 0
if (Interlocked.Increment(ref x) == 2)
{
   // do something only once
}
```

This is of course not thread safe: if at run time the first thread is stopped after `x` was incremented but before the evaluation, and then the second thread increments `x` so it is now 2, then the `if` statement is `true`. Then we return to the first thread and it also gets true in the `if` statement.

This can be fixed by surrounding the code by the `lock` statement.

Is there a way to make it thread safe without using the `lock` statement?

Comment: Your described scenario won't occur because the return value of the `Interlocked.Increment()` method cannot be changed by other threads.

Comment: Your code *may* be unsafe if it later accesses `x` again and assumes it's the same as the result of the increment, but you've not shown code here that demonstrates this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is of course not thread safe since if at run time the first thread is stopped after x was incremented but before the evaluation. Then the second thread increments and x is know 2 so the if statement is true.Then we return to the first thread and it is know also true.

This is not true.

`Interlocked.Increment` is an atomic operation no extra `lock` is required. (otherwise what whould be the point of that?)

The value is being incremented and you get the incremented value.  Even if another increment happened afterwards, you still have the first incremented value. so the if will evaluate to false.

Your code for that matter is thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are incorrect in your assumption.  The return value from  `Interlocked.Increment` is the value after the increment, not the value of `x` at evaluation time.   It is entirely possible that `x` could have been changed by another thread, so the following would be true:

```
int x = 1;
var y = Interlocked.Increment(ref x);

if(x!=y)
```